# Geometric mean pivot

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, quicksort

I am PhD student and I am working on my project,

I want to know what will be worst case partition time complexity if I am using geometric mean as pivot to partitioning array into approximate two equal part?

results :-

Vladimir Yaroslavskiy dual pivot quickselect  partition :-  2307601193 nanosecond

Geometric mean pivot quickselect  partition  :-  8661916394 nanosecond

We know that it is very costly and make quick partition much slower. There are many algorithms Which are much faster than quick select to find median but in our project we are not going to use them directly.

Example of Geometric mean pivot:-

> ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> Input-   789654123 ,  700 ,  10^20 ,    588412  ,    900     , 5           ,    500
>
> Geometric mean :-( 789654123*700*10^20*588412*900*5*500)^(1/7)= 1846471
>
> Pass 1- 500        700     5       588412     900   |<---> |    10^20     789654123
>
> Geometric mean :-(500*700*5*588412*900)^(1/5)=984
>
> Pass 2-  500,       700,        5,              900,   |<---> |  588412,    10^20,     789654123
>   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

By this way we can divide array into approximate two equal parts.

My question is what will be worst case( worst unbalanced partitioning ) time complexity if i am using geometric mean as pivot to partitioning array into approximate two equal part?

Note:- we are not using -ve no in data set.

Comment: Calculation and partitioning are both `O(n)`, so of course the time complexity is `O(n)`. I believe you are asking for the most unbalanced partitioning, and there `±INF`, `0`, and negative numbers are all going to throw you off for at least one iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2<sup>2<sup>0</sup></sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>1</sup></sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup>, ..., 2<sup>2<sup>n - 1</sup></sup> have geometric mean

> (2<sup>2<sup>0</sup></sup> · 2<sup>2<sup>1</sup></sup> · 2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup> · ... · 2<sup>2<sup>n - 1</sup></sup>)<sup>(1 / n)</sup>
>
> = (2<sup>2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + ... 2<sup>n</sup></sup>)<sup>(1 / n)</sup>
>
> = (2<sup>2<sup>n+1</sup> - 1</sup>)<sup>(1/n)</sup>
>
> = 2<sup>(2<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) / n</sup>
>
> = 2<sup>(2<sup>n+1</sup> - 1) 2<sup>-log n</sup></sup>
>
> = 2<sup>(2<sup>n+1 - log n</sup> - log n)</sup>

Notice that this number is (approximately) 2<sup>2<sup>n - log n</sup></sup>. This means that your partition will only split approximately log n terms into the second group of the array, which is a very small number compared to the overall array size. Consequently, you'd expect that for data sets of this sort, you'd have closer to Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) performance than to Θ(n log n) performance. However, I can't get an exact asymptotic value for this because I don't know how exactly how many rounds there will be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this answer! However the implication for 64-bit floats is that there are ~10 items in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Geometric mean is equivalent to the arithmetic mean of the logarithm, so we just need to find something where arithmetic mean breaks down badly and take the exponent of it.  One example would be factorials, if you have a list

```
1!, 2!, 3!, 4!, ..., n!
```

taking the arithmetic mean will split exactly before the last element.  Proof:  The sum of this array is larger than the last element:

```
s_n > n!
```

Consequently the arithmetic mean is larger than the element before it:

```
av_n = s_n/n > (n-1)!
```

As a result quick select requires n rounds and its performance will be O(n^2), in contrast to the average performance which would be O(n).  To get the same behavior with the geometric mean you have to consider the list of exponents of this

```
a^(1!), a^(2!), ..., a^(n!)
```

for any `a>1` or `0<a<1`.  The resulting performance of a *quick-select* based on the geometric mean would be O(n^2).